# router still initializing when route called

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to get my app to load all the data when the router is initialized. It works fine to load the data, problem is when I try to go to a route that needs that data too quickly it hasn't loaded the data yet. How do I get the data to load first and wait until the router is completely initialized to process my route view "schedule"?

```
  window.IrdbWeb = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
          '':   'home',
          'schedule/':  'schedule' 
      },
      initialize: function() {

          window.encoderStream = new Stream();
          window.scheduleLibrary = new Schedules();
          window.recordingLibrary = new Records();


          $.when(window.encoderStream.fetch(),window.recordingLibrary.fetch(), window.scheduleLibrary.fetch()).done(function(){

                this.scheduleLibraryView = new ScheduleLibraryView({
                        collection:   window.scheduleLibrary 
                    });
          });

          // Player model
          this.player = new Player();                 

          this.playerView = new PlayerView({
                      player: this.player
          });

          $('div#overlay').fadeOut(800);

      },
      home: function() {

      },
      schedule: function() {        

        $("#info").empty().append(this.scheduleLibraryView.render().el);

      }
  });

window.App = new IrdbWeb();
Backbone.history.start();
```

If I go from home -> schedule it works because the route has time to initialize the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.when(window.encoderStream.fetch(),
       window.recordingLibrary.fetch(), 
       window.scheduleLibrary.fetch()
).done(function(){
    this.scheduleLibraryView = new ScheduleLibraryView({
        collection: window.scheduleLibrary 
    });

    // all data has been fetched, start routing!
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

However, this is actually an anti-pattern. From the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page
>   load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped
>   in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for
>   interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents
>   with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.